# iOS APNs badge update issue

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Say, i have an app with APNs on. the app icon badge number is only up to the badge property of the APNs JSON payload, right ? That means if currently the app icon badge is 1, when a new push notification arrives, the app icon badge will be changed to the badge value of the JSON payload, but not auto increase by 1, if that right ?
if so, is there an approach to do that auto increase. or is there a way to get the total notification count for an app in the notification center? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the JSON payload you're actually setting the badge number. The only solution is to manage it server side by notifying the server each time a "notification" is read.

You should add a "read" flag to your objects in the database that are sent as notifications.
So for a chat app for example:
When you send a notification for a new message, the badge number should be the total of all the conversations with unread flags for that user. And each time the user reads a conversation, you should make an API call to mark it as read in your server and of course decrement the badge number locally.

Comment: thanks, i got your point. seems like the only solution is to manage it at server side.